# How to properly sort in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

There are products

```
name                       | price | company_id

product 1 of the company 1 | 10    | 1
product 2 of the company 1 | 10    | 1
product 3 of the company 1 | 20    | 1
product 4 of the company 2 | 10    | 2
product 5 of the company 2 | 10    | 2
product 6 of the company 2 | 20    | 2
product 7 of the company 3 | 10    | 3
product 8 of the company 3 | 10    | 3
product 9 of the company 3 | 20    | 3
```

It is required to sort by price and by company id, but that the companies alternate

And we got this result

```
name                       | price | company_id

product 1 of the company 1 | 10    | 1
product 4 of the company 2 | 10    | 2
product 7 of the company 3 | 10    | 3
product 2 of the company 1 | 10    | 1
product 5 of the company 2 | 10    | 2
product 8 of the company 3 | 10    | 3
product 3 of the company 1 | 20    | 1
product 6 of the company 2 | 20    | 2
product 9 of the company 3 | 20    | 3
```

I don't know how to Google it correctly, where can I read about such sorting?

Comment: Can you please post your current query.

Comment: can you please also add your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

This script will order by price and then alternate using the id field:

```
GET your-index/_search
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "price": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
    {
      "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "script": {
          "source": "if (doc['company_id'].value % 2 == 0) { return -1; } else { return 1; }"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can tweak the script to sort in any way you need.

More about script sort:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html#script-based-sorting

Comment: i think so it will show  two recoreds with 10-2 on top and then two recoreds with 10-1 and 10-3